# How can I associate css to html string, received from server?

Tags: c#, html, css, webview, microsoft-metro

I'm working on a metro app.
Say I receive a string (html) and I load that string in a webview. 
How can I associate a .css to that html?

Update:

WebViewColumnRight as suggested in an answers is an android method; I'm working on a metro app, c#.

Comment: Provide a 'html string' for example. Is it a complete page (with header) or just an ajax part ?

Comment: a complete page also with css reference.

Comment: Well, then just build a normal web page.
JanivZ gave you the +100 answer.

Comment: ignore the webview responses embedd your returned html string with the css you require, either a s a <link> or in a <style> tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As JanivZ said the one way is that your returned html string should contain the reference to the required CSS so that it can be loaded automatically.

or the other option you have is, you can use [WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

```
htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" +    htmlData;
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, htmlData, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

After this WebView will be able to find your CSS file from the base URL directory. And if both HTML and CSS are coming from the same base URL then no need to specify a baseURL in webView.loadDataWithBaseURL

Comment: I'm developing a metro app with c# and xaml. Not an android one!

Comment: Ohh sorry i guess i missed that part in your question that you are using Metro App. my bad. But the basic logic will remain same i guess. I means you just need to concat the link refrence and load the page.

Comment: I know, but I cannot find any useful function to do that.

Comment: @Sam ... Not sure of any such method in metro apps. But i found one article if this can solve your problem. Please have a look at this [Link](http://blog.jsolutions.co.uk/?p=492)

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the 'returned string' should contain the references necessary to load the css file ( like below for example)

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
</head>
```

and have the elements in it reference rules defined in that css file.
No ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing a `WEBVIEW.NavigateToString(stringHtmlContent)` then please inject a

`string styleSheetString = "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='test.css' />"`

```
strUpdatedHtmlContent = stringHtmlContent.Insert(stringHtmlContent.IndexOf("<head>",styleSheetString);
```

then do

`WEBVIEW.NavigateToString(strUpdatedHtmlContent)`

I just hope this helps. O one more thing please take care of the path of the css and all which I just figured from the above discussions...

Comment: I think is the only way ... OR ... maybe saving the html in a file, in an external directory where is also placed the style.css, is another way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

**External stylesheet that points to full path where css file can be found.**

```
 <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="full path to css file on server">
    </head>
```

**Internal Style Sheet that comes with your html and requires no dependency on a css file**

```
<head>
<style>
hr {color:sienna;}
p {margin-left:20px;}
body {background-image:url("images/back40.gif");}
</style>
</head>
```

**Inline Style is a messier way to do what an Internal style sheet does(has no dependency on external css file)**

```
<p style="color:sienna;margin-left:20px">This is a paragraph.</p>
```