# Webview always on top (Metro app)

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, windows-runtime, z-index

I've noticed that whenever you have a WebView on your screen, it will be the top-most element of the UI. Is there a way to set a z-index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to set z-index or anything similar, WebView is always on top of the XAML ("Airspace" issue). You have to hide web view if new content completely hides WebView or use WebViewBrush control.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2012/10/18/nine-things-you-need-to-know-about-webview.aspx#AN2

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2012/08/13/how-to-display-charms-on-a-top-of-the-webview.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webviewbrush.aspx

Comment: Thank you. Could you have a look on this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424051/how-can-i-associate-css-to-html-string-received-from-server

Comment: as far I can see you allready have good answer, just link css

Answer (score 0):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx:

> Note  The "airspace problem" has been fixed starting with Windows 8.1.