# Take control to front

Tags: c#, webview, windows-runtime

I placed a ComboBox and WebView in a grid but when I open ComboBox some of its items missed; its going back to WebView. I tried to put it separate from WebView but still the same issue.

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <Button Height="80" Width="200" Margin="100,5,0,30">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Image Source="/Assets/Images/refresh.png" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>

    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <ComboBox x:Name="ddl" Margin="100,-45,1070,660">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lumia" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lumia" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lumia" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lumia" />
        </ComboBox>
        <WebView x:Name="wview" />
    </Grid>
  </grid>
```

I also tried to put it after "refresh button" but the same issue.

Comment: You are working on Windows8 or Windows8.1 project ??

Comment: my windows is 8.1, VS2012 .. not mentioned in VS its 8.1 or 8 project

Comment: If you are working on VS2012 then you must be working on Windows8, Windows8.1 projects are available on VS2013 only

Comment: Have you tried to play on Canvas.Zindex

Comment: I don't follow your question as there's no WebView in your code. Search for "airspace" on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br227702) page to see if it addresses the problem you're describing.

Comment: you did not see <Grid Grid.Row="1"> Its in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14564593/959687

It will explain how to solve your problem and why WebView is always on top.